# HTML code same for each image, links not all working

Tags: html

I've coded http://www.meghanbustardphotography.com/home/ and have linked each image to a different page (html code below). However, only the first link in each row is functioning. How can I fix this?

```
<div class="row" class="aligncenter">
    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.meghanbustardphotography.com/blog/2014/09/colin-karlee-abbotsford-backyard-wedding/">
        <div id="colinkarlee"></div>
    </a>
    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.meghanbustardphotography.com/blog/2014/09/andrew-rebecca-whytecliff-park-engagement/">
        <div id="andrewrebecca"></div>
    </a>
    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.meghanbustardphotography.com/blog/2014/05/justin-hilary-south-bonson-wedding-2/">
        <div id="justinhilary"></div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="row" class="aligncenter">
    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.meghanbustardphotography.com/blog/2014/07/greg-amanda-beach-grove-wedding/">
        <div id="gregamanda"></div>
    </a>
    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.meghanbustardphotography.com/blog/2014/10/cory-nicole-fort-langley-little-white-house-wedding/">
        <div id="corynicole"></div>
    </a>
    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.meghanbustardphotography.com/blog/2013/09/mike-renae-whonnock-lake-portraits/">
        <div id="mikerenae"></div>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="row" class="aligncenter">
    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.meghanbustardphotography.com/blog/2014/08/david-gastown-portraits/">
        <div id="david"></div>
    </a>
    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.meghanbustardphotography.com/blog/2014/09/brent-stephanie/">
        <div id="brentstephanie"></div>
    </a>
    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.meghanbustardphotography.com/blog/2014/08/sean-brittany-langley-golf-centre-wedding/">
        <div id="seanbrittany"></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please define "functioning." What do you expected to happen, and what is happening now?

Comment: They're referring to the picture links.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think it might wordpress not processing/showing your HTML directly. Try these:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/allow-php-in-posts-and-pages/

Answer (score 1):

By taking a look at your real page, only 1st column has < div > inside < a >< /a >

```
<a href="http://www.meghanbustardphotography.com/blog/2014/09/colin-karlee-abbotsford-backyard-wedding/" target="_blank">
    <div id="colinkarlee"></div>
</a>
```

For 2nd and 3 column, I see the < div >(s) are outside of < a >< /a >. That's the reason why they are not clickable

```
<div id="andrewrebecca"></div>
<a href="http://www.meghanbustardphotography.com/blog/2014/09/andrew-rebecca-whytecliff-park-engagement/" target="_blank"> </a>

<div id="justinhilary"></div>
<a href="http://www.meghanbustardphotography.com/blog/2014/05/justin-hilary-south-bonson-wedding-2/" target="_blank"> </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `<div id == ... >`
INTO `<a target .. /a>`

I did it and the links worked after that.

I can provide pictures if you don't know what I mean

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of `<p>` links in your view page source code that do not have closing `</p>` tags associated with them. Try taking those out and see if that helps.

Also, check out the order of the `<a>` and `<div>` tags in your actual code. They're not matching what you pasted in your question.